# ngrep how to make match expression case insensitive?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, grep

Quote from man page

```
match expression
A  match  expression  is either an extended regular expression, or if the -X
option is specified, a string signifying a hexadecimal value.   An  extended
regular  expression  follows  the  rules  as  implemented  by  the GNU regex
library.  Hexadecimal expressions can optionally be preceded by `0x'.  E.g.,
`DEADBEEF', `0xDEADBEEF'.
```

For (e)grep I use `-i`,but how to write a ngrep match expression that case insensitive ?

e.g.

```
sudo ngrep -xqtd lo0 select port 3306
```

Will not match `mysql --protocol=tcp -e "Select 1"` ?

Comment: what man page are you quoting? `ngrep`? Also, both in http://www.softpanorama.org/Net/Netutils/ngrep.shtml and  http://ngrep.sourceforge.net/usage.html they mention the `-i` option. What do you get if you use it?

Comment: Sorry, I missed this, when I check the man page, I searched insensitive, but I should search case I will find -i option.This question is useless, should I delete it ?

Comment: No, it may be good for next people checking it. I will post an answer to make it clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As read in the [`man page`](http://www.softpanorama.org/Net/Netutils/ngrep.shtml), you have the `-i` option for this:

> **-i**
>
> Perform a case-insensitive search.